# How to stop Lambda from incurring CloudTrail charges related to CreateLogStream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda

I manage an actually not very big website, but Lambda is used extensively, invoked many times per site visit, resulting in hundreds of thousands of calls per month.

I noticed a spike in CloudTrail costs. Digging further I found that the biggest offender is calls to `CreateLogStream` made by the Lambda infrastructure, i.e. *it is AWS's code doing this, not mine*. My CloudTrail costs due to CreateLogStream are 100x the Lambda costs (Lambda's Free Tier distorts this ratio somewhat).

Short of completely deactivating `CloudTrail`, is there any way to stop incurring these charges?

Comment: CloudTrail pricing "The first copy of management events within each region is delivered free of charge. Additional copies of management events are charged $2.00 per 100,000 events. Data events are charged at $0.10 per 100,000 events.". How many request are being made, and what is it costing you? Data events are disabled by default.

Comment: We're facing the same issue and it's costing us a lot of money. Seems crazy that there's no way to turn off this useless logging.

Comment: @Tim's question is a good one - the first copy of a management event should be free, so unless you've got multiple trails set up this shouldn't be occurring?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudtrail-data-management-events/ - has more info on what type of event things are.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use [Advanced Event Selectors](https://awscloudfeed.com/whats-new/management-tools/how-to-optimize-aws-cloudtrail-costs-by-using-advanced-event-selectors) on the trail config to exclude/include specific sources, lambdas, etc. for data events.

Update: I've tested this myself. I can create a trail to monitor all Lambda (data) events, with a filter for a specific one. I can then invert the filter to exclude that one. But I'm not sure if it's going to exclude the actual `createLogStream` calls, as that might be on a different object.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible for you to test if you could exclude those calls?